# Is there a derogatory word for "mobile phone" (cellphone) similar to "idiot box" for a television?

Tags: slang, pejorative-language

My father called our TV "the idiot box".  Implying either that it had idiots on it, was targeted at idiots, or you were an idiot if you watched it too much.

Is there any similar term in use but referring to mobile phones?

Comment: Perhaps iDiot Box? (With an app, can be accessed by Twiddiots).

Comment: if you keep using it, you will join the ranks of *mobots* (or iPhonies?).

Comment: I don't know, chatterbox? In Dutch we use *lulijzer*...

Comment: There’s always *JesusPhone*, used pejoratively for iPhones.

Comment: WW, *[derogative](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/derogative#Adjective)* in your title appears to be grammatically ok and might be natural usage, but I'd have written *[derogatory](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/derogatory#Adjective)* instead.

Comment: @jwpat7 Agree - edited

Answer (score 7):

While [***electronic leash***](http://everything2.com/title/electronic+leash) was traditionally the derogatory term for a pager, with the demise of pagers and the ubiquity of cell phones I imagine the term could be carried over to phones now.

Comment: Any evidence of currency?

Answer (score 6):

In an similar vein to *idiot box*, a derogatory name for someone who uses their mobile phone a lot is ***smartphone zombie***. From [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Smartphone-Zombie):

> A person that is constantly focused on his or her smartphone, ignoring the environment and especially other people.
>
> *Dude 1: Hey you see that girl over there? She looks good right?*
>
> *Dude 2: Sure, but I´d stay away from her man, she´s one of those smartphone-zombies.*

Here's a [CNN story](http://edition.cnn.com/2012/10/03/tech/smartphone-zombie-apocalypse-comments/index.html) on *smartphone zombies*, and a [Flickr collection of photos](http://www.flickr.com/groups/2262744@N23/).

Answer (score 3):

The dependence that corporate drive placed on slavish attention to the Blackberry led to it being called a *[Crackberry](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/crackberry)*.

*[iPhonitis](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=iPhonitis)* refers to digital injury due to overuse.

Comment: fondleSlab for iPad is common among techies

Comment: what about nokia,samsung,htc? this is just for iphone and blackberry?

Comment: @JavaD Maybe *nokiaknuckle*? There was a condition involving overuse of the forearm that, in the 1980s was named *Pac-man elbow*. A term is often coined based on the most popular trend that causes is at the time. Other brands lose the glory of a disease being named after them.

Answer (score 0):

*[Blower](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blower#Noun)* is a dated slang term for the telephone. I think of it as a negative term (due to associated senses of *blower* like “A braggart, or loud talker”) but don't know whether it's commonly seen as negative in reference to telephones.

Comment: Blower is not a negative term for a telephone. If you have ever watched old movies where the sailors on ships communicate with each other by blowing a whistle before speaking down a voice pipe, you can see its origin.

Answer (score 0):

May be we can call "The Junk Box" ?

Comment: may be the "junk compass" as its proper to say compass then a box to a phone size. :)